# Scraping flex tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would to scrape the paragraphs of a web site with BeautifulSoup, but there are flex boxes in the webpage so the program can't find the chosen tag.

```
def content_article(url, file_output):
    """scrape content  web page in a file and the plain code

       url: address of web page of international federation of canoe

       file_output: file name created + plain file name

       return two files: file with HTML code and file with only text information
       """
    response = requests.get(url)
    data= response.content
    soup = bs(data, features="html.parser")
    plain_soup = soup.encode("UTF-8")
    section = soup.find("div", {"class" : "container"})
    print (section)
    paragraphes = section.find_all("p")
    result=""
    for paragraphe in paragraphes:
        print ("paragraphe")
        print(paragraphe)
        result = result + paragraphe.text + "\n"
        print("result")
        print (result)
    url_file = file_output + ".txt"
    file = open(url_file, 'w', encoding="utf_8")
    file.write("infos provenant de" + url + "\n")
    file.write(result)
    file.close()
    url_plain_file = file_output + "_plain.txt"
    plain_file = open(url_plain_file, 'w')
    plain_file.write(str(plain_soup))
    plain_file.close()
    print("the file " + file_output + " has been created")
```

Example URL: https://www.fifa.com/about-fifa/president/news/gianni-infantino-congratulates-shaikh-salman-on-re-election-as-afc-president

The program can't find the tag "container" because it is in a flex tag.

I tried to use Selenium but I couldn't find the "activated" flex box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The program can't find the tag "container" because it is in a flex tag.

You don't need to worry about the flexboxes as they won't affect the presence of html elements. I think they are used in a particular website layout model to make web dev easier.

I'm not sure what you mean by a "container" tag as I don't believe this tag type exists in html.

> I tried to use Selenium but I couldn't find the "activated" flex box.

It works with selenium. Perhaps you were running it headless or altered some of the options?

###### Solution

Try this. I split up the different subtasks into individual functions and then made
one function (i.e. `main`) that combines them. It produces your desired output, namely 2 text files: one with the html elements (i.e. p tags) that contain the text and one with only the text.

Edit: I just realized that `p` tags with classes `p-large ff-text-grey-slate` are also used to store the 3 bullet points at the top of the article and 2 empty lines at the bottom of the article. Thus, the final output will contain these values.

Due to the websites html structure I'm not sure how to simply solve this issue. Try to find any patterns that you can exploit to only the `p` tags that only contain the values you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

def get_page_source(url):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        sleep(3)
        return driver.page_source
    finally: driver.quit()

def store_elements(outpath, p_tags):
    print(p_tags)
    with open(outpath, mode='w') as file:
        file.writelines(p_tags)

def store_texts(outpath, texts):
    with open(outpath, mode='w') as file:
        file.writelines(texts)

def get_elements(page_source, tag_name, attr):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
    return soup.find_all(tag_name, attr)

def get_text_from_elements(elements):
    return [element.text for element in elements]

def main(html_path, text_path, url):
    pg_source = get_page_source(url)
    p_tags = get_elements(pg_source, 'p', {'class':'p-large ff-text-grey-slate'})
    texts = get_text_from_elements(p_tags)
    store_elements(html_path, p_tags)
    store_texts(text_path, texts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.fifa.com/about-fifa/president/news/gianni-infantino-congratulates-shaikh-salman-on-re-election-as-afc-president"

    # enter 2 paths, one for the html and other for the paragraphs (i.e. texts)
    main('', '', url)
```